# How can i add a a roof overhang?

Tags: java, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am trying to create a building using Citygml4j library. The building should have building parts and overhangs. When examined I saw use of the `BuildingInstallation` class for building elements like balconies and overhangs. But I don't understand how to use it. 
I created a building. It has only roof and wall. How i add roof overhang a building using citygml4j library?

Thanks...

Comment: Can you point out an example of `BuildingInstallation` and what you don't understand? Your question is currently too broad. (and the code you put in your question not exactly what [ask] means with [mcve])